# How to stop showing multiple times of data in datagridview while retrieving from database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm working with win-forms.I have a datagridview which is loaded its data from 2 tables of SQL database And I want to load data to datagridview as the data to be shown only once.
Here `dtp` is datetimepicker,the query i wanted is `s_no` should be from `dailyattendance`
    (later I increment the `s_no` value as if last `S_no` is 10 in the table increases its value to 
    `11,12,13` and so on while data is loading to datagridview)  table and  remaining 
    columns should be from employee details.
When I use below code ,the datagridview is binding with many reputations,that I dont want

```
private void bindgrid()
   {

       try
       {
           dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 10;
           ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
           string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
           using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
               cn.Open();


               string dtp = dateTimePicker3grd.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
//in this query if use ON d.Employee_Id =  e.Employee_Id query
// it is showing only equal values with no reputation,so i tried to ON d.Employee_Id !=  e.Employee_Id query then many reputations are occurring.I dont want this
               string query = "SELECT d.S_No,e.Employee_id,e.Employee_name,e.image_of_employee  
                                FROM dailyattendance d JOIN employee_details e 
ON d.Employee_Id =  e.Employee_Id  where e.Employee_Id  not in (select  Employee_Id from dailyattendance where date = '" + dtp + "' ) ";



               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
               using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
               {
                   using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                   {
                       sda.Fill(dt);


                       int maxSlNo = int.Parse(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["S_No"].ToString());
                       maxSlNo++;
                       foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                       {
                           dtRow["S_No"] = maxSlNo;
                           maxSlNo++;

                       }

                       dt.AcceptChanges();

                       dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "S_No";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "S_No";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "S_No";


                       dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Employee_id";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Employee_Id";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Employee_id";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Employee_name";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Employee_Name";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Employee_name";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "In_time";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "In_time";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Out_time";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Out_time";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Date";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Date";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Week_no_of_the_Month";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Week_no_of_the_Month";


                       dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Attendance";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "Attendance";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "Work_status";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Work_status";

                       dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "Remarks";
                       dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Remarks";
// for Image_Of_employee I did not give column but automatically displaying in datagridview last column's cells



                       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                   }

               }
           }
       }

       catch(Exception e1)

       {
           MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
       }


   }
```

I called this method in form load()

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you use distinct in your sql query

Comment: You should really put all the db-stuff in at least a separate method and preferably a separate class, [use a usings for the SqlConnection](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx), avoid sql injection by [using parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter),...

Comment: no i did not use distinct in my query
where should i place it in query @SmartDeveloper

Comment: From the database you are getting the results duplicate or in datagridview you are having the issue, if on datagridview you need to set the property of datagridview `AllowUserToAddRows=false`

Comment: I used ' AllowUserToAddRows=false',still the problem is existing @Dotnet

Comment: Then execute your query in SQL and check whether it is giving multiple results if yes then you need to modify your query based on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
string query = "SELECT d.S_No,e.Employee_id,e.Employee_name,e.image_of_Employee 
FROM dailyattendance as d,employee_details AS e where e.Employee_Id  
not in (select  Employee_Id from dailyattendance where date = '" + dtp + "' ) 
Order By d.S_No";
```

with

```
string query = "SELECT DISTINCT d.S_No,e.Employee_id,e.Employee_name,e.image_of_Employee 
FROM dailyattendance d JOIN employee_details e ON d.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id  
not in (select  Employee_Id from dailyattendance where date = '" + dtp + "' ) 
Order By d.S_No";
```

Comment: @ShivaDebrown I will not recommend not in due to not in will affect on performance

Comment: @Shiva Debrown please mention error which you are getting

Comment: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'not'.` this error throwing.  

my complete query is `SELECT DISTINCT d.S_No,e.Employee_id,e.Employee_name,e.image_of_Employee 
FROM dailyattendance d JOIN employee_details e ON d.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id  
not in (select  Employee_Id from dailyattendance where date = '02/10/2014' ) 
Order By d.S_No`

Comment: @Shiva Debrown Please update your Question and add your Table structure so i can check it from my side, if possible

Comment: Please show me table fields name and datatype  not Table data i will make new tables like your table and then I can say something.. show me table Script

Comment: I have added a images of my tables,Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You select data from 2 tables, but you didn't join tables. You ought to change the part of your query from

```
FROM dailyattendance as d,employee_details AS e
```

to

```
FROM dailyattendance d JOIN employee_details e ON d.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id
```